# .Net 6.0 Session Timeout Redirection during Ajax call

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, session, azure-active-directory, .net-6.0

I am using Azure AD authentication on .Net 6.0 Asp.Net core web application. After session gets timed out I made a ajax call.. its trying to redirecting to login.mircosoftonline.com but getting CORS error in browser Network tab.. there is no change in the UI.. My question is when session gets timed out how do I force browser to reauthenticate and complete the Ajax call or show the session timed out page? The IIS AppPool  timeout was set to 20 minutes. Below is the my setting in Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options => {
    options.AddPolicy("ReadWrite", policyBuilder => policyBuilder.RequireClaim("groups", builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("AuthorizedGroups:mygroupname")));    
});
```

Comment: `made a ajax call.. its trying to redirecting to login.mircosoftonline.com` this will lead to CORS issue because microsft identity platform only allow request from MSAL. so when your app noticed the session had timeout and want to let user resign again, you should trigger the sign in action. Since you integrate AAD in your .net 6 web app, then you should also have a _LoginPartial.cshtml which provided sign in action.

Comment: like this `<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn">Sign in</a>`

Comment: I did not get completely... Will this link triggers sign in automatically when session got timed out?

Comment: no, it won't be  triggered automatically